# import file in same dir

Tags: python, import

Both files are in the same directory. How can I make the Axe class available to main.py ?

```
# axe.py
class Axe:
    name = 'Name'
```

---

```
# main.py
import axe
my_axe = Axe()
```

---

```
NameError: "name 'Axe' is not defined"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either want `from axe import Axe`, or `my_axe = axe.Axe()`.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
# main.py
import axe
my_axe = axe.Axe()
```

or:

```
# main.py
from axe import * # Or "import Axe" to just get Axe and not everything
my_axe = Axe()
```

The former is preferred, because if two modules have the same name defined, they won't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference the class directly, then @carlpett's answer will work, otherwise you need to reference the class by it's module, i.e:

```
import axe
my_axe = axe.Axe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following.

```
import axe
my_axe = axe.Axe()
```

Or

```
from axe import Axe
my_axe = Axe()
```